# Issue with jquery datatable row adding in client side

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need your help.

I'm working with jquery datatables and I'm having problems with rows adding.

This is my html code:

```
...
    <div>
        <a href="#modal-form" role="button" data-toggle="modal">New user</a>
    </div>
    <table id="dynamic-table" role="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <th class="center sorting_disabled"><input class="ace" type="checkbox"></th>
                <th class="sorting">ID</th>
                <th class="sorting">First name</th>
                <th class="sorting">Second name</th>
                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
                <td class="center"><input class="ace" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Adam</td>
                <td>Duritz</td>
                <td><a href="#modal-form" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ...
```

When clicking both href it is opened a modal form, for new record and edit row. In modal form there is a save button.

This is my jquery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

        //initiate dataTables plugin
        var myTable =
        $('#dynamic-table')
        .DataTable({
            bAutoWidth: false,
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
            "aaSorting": [],
            select: {
                style: 'multi'
            }
        });

        // handler href click (for new row and edit), open modal form
        $('a[href="#modal-form"]').click(function () {
            // code ....
        });

        // handler save button click in modal form
        $("#btnSaveDetail").click(function () {
            myTable.row.add([
                '<input class="ace" type="checkbox">',
                $('#cph_main_rec_id').val(),
                $('#cph_main_txt_fname').val(),
                $('#cph_main_txt_sname').val(),
                '<a href="#modal-form" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>')
                .nodes()
                .to$()
                .attr('role', 'row')
                .find('td:eq(0)')
                .addClass('center');

            myTable.draw();
            $('#modal-form').modal('hide');
        })
    })
```

The referenced code for adding row in client side work properly, the new row is added and shown (displaying the html code, the new row is correct).

But, when I click the edit button, the href handler it is not called.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks to those who can help me.
Mauro

Comment: Your handler runs prior to the row being added. You need to add the handler after adding the row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I did not understand what handler you're talking about. Href handler run modal form, instead button handler save new or changes data. If I click the edit button in first row, href handler work properly. If I click the edito button of new added row handler not work.

Comment: So, you have handler code `$('a[href="#modal-form"]').click(function () { ....` and then you have "SaveDetail" code `$("#btnSaveDetail").click(function () { .... $('#cph_main_txt_sname').val(), '<a href="#modal-form" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>')` which occurs after you add the handler. In other words, the handler doesn't get applied because the row on the table with the `href="#modal-form"` code is added after you add your handler.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Then, how can I add a new row with href in a td?

Comment: Basically, your handler doesn't find your edit button because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I am thinking that this: `$('a[href="#modal-form"]').click(function () { ...` needs to be a function in which you pass an element to it. The function would then add the on click functionality. That way after you click to add the edit button happens you call that function and pass in the new Edit button element as an argument.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help. I think I understand what you mean. Perhaps it is enough to create a new function that call "#modal-form" jquery function. Thanks again.